# Closed-form solution to the problem: $\arg\min_{q \in \Delta_{\mathcal X} \text{ s.t } \|q-p\|_2 \le \epsilon} \mathbb E_q[X]$

Tags: probability, statistics, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $p$ be a probability distribution on countable set $\mathcal X$, denoted $p \in \mathcal X$.

## Question

- What is an "closed-form" solution for the problem: $\underset{q \in \Delta_{\mathcal X} \text{ s.t } \|q-p\|_2 \le \epsilon}{\arg\min} \mathbb E_q[X]$ ?
- What if $\mathcal X$ is finite ? Not that in that case, the problem reduces to
  $$
  \underset{q \in \Delta_{k} \text{ s.t } \|q-p\|_2 \le \epsilon}{\arg\min} \sum_{i=1}^kq_ix_i,
  $$
  where $k$ is the number of elements in $\mathcal X$, $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \in \mathbb R^k$ (fixed), and $\Delta_k \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ is the $(k-1)$-dimensional probability simplex.

Comment: I didn't know about \arg. Thanks.

Comment: How do you define $\| q - p \|_2$ for two probability distributions?

Comment: $\|p-q\|_2^2 := \sum_{x \in \mathcal X} |p_x-q_x|^2$